# How is base damage calculated?

Tags: part-time-gods

Despite searching the whole book I did only find modifications for the base damage but not how it is calculated originally.
Thus my question how is it calculated originally?

Answer (score 2):

It defaults to 0 unless you have Gifts, Entitlements and so on that affect it.

Comment: Thanks for contributing an answer! Could it be enhanced by adding a reference to where in the book this is established, or what reasoning otherwise leads to this conclusion? (You can [edit] to add such improvements to a post.)

Comment: @SevenSidedDie In the meantime I found one review myself stating the same with the cvomment that it is indicated a few times.....but never mentioned explicitely. So not sure if a reference by Eloy will be possible there. although.....he looks like th emaker of the game (picture and also nickwise)?